# How to fix google sub module import error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-iot

I'm trying to run the following command in cloud sdk to send a command to cloud IOT

```sh
python3 main.py --send_command="$RESPONSE" --registry=REGISTRY NAME --device=DEVICE NAME --cloud_region=europe-west1 --project_id=PROJECT ID send-command
```

I am getting the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    from google.api_core.exceptions import AlreadyExists
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google
```

I tried the following workarounds but had no luck.

```sh
pip install --upgrade google-api-core
pip install google-cloud
pip install google-cloud-vision
```

Have I missed any libraries?

Python version - Python 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already and willing to consider using [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/), it may help (!) resolve the issue because it provides a 'clean room':

```sh
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then check the current modules:

```sh
pip3 freeze
```

Returns no install modules

Then either:

```sh
pip3 install google-api-core
pip3 install google-cloud-vision
pip3 freeze
```

Or, preferably create `requirements.txt`:

```
google-api-core==1.21.0
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
```

And:

```sh
pip3 install --requirement ./requirements.txt
pip3 freeze
```

Returns:

```
cachetools==4.1.0
certifi==2020.4.5.2
chardet==3.0.4
google-api-core==1.21.0
google-auth==1.18.0
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
idna==2.9
protobuf==3.12.2
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
rsa==4.6
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.25.9
```

> **NOTE** the list and versions will change

Then checking the import will suceed:

```sh
python3 -c "from google.api_core.exceptions import AlreadyExists"
```